# How to remove lines from a text file words list?

Tags: bash

I want to remove all occurrences of all the words in this file lines

file1 > word_list.txt

file2 > list.txt

Example:

File1:

```
alpha
pico
station
```

File2:

```
welcome to my panel alpha
forever pico its vey nice
happy to see you
Petrol  : station welcome 
Are you all right
Petrol  | station | its nice
```

Output :

```
happy to see you
Are you all right
```

how can remove Lines that contain words

Comment: If your other question, with one word per line in the sample, didn't reflect your actual data, you should unselect the answer and edit that question to better reflect what you're dealing with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `grep -v` (invert matches) for that:

```
$ grep -v -F -f word_list.txt file1.txt
happy to see you
Are you all right
```

`-f` makes your patterns be read from the file word_list.txt, `-v` makes you output only lines *not* matching them, and `-F` makes `grep` match the results literally, without trying to interpret more complex expressions (in case you have "words" with special characters in your word lists).

You could also use `-w`, which matches only words, removing false positives like "add" matching "addition".

Comment: this code not work to me

Comment: You'll want `-F` and `-x` too.

Comment: Thanks, `-F` is definitely desired if you only want literal matches. I don't think `-x` is desired though, since that means only lines with only that word will be matched.

Comment: Maybe you meant `-w`? That could be good, too.

Comment: Yeah, I meant w. brain fart.